# Use of the word "test" in email subject >>> any impact on deliverability?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, deliverability

we often send internal TEST emails in Content builder > Preview and Test, by manually entering emails addresses of the recipients of the test emails.

In the subject of the emails, we use most the time "TEST... something..."

Can the fact that we use the word "test" in the subject of the emails affect the global deliverability of the email and the reputation of the IP ?

Thanks

regards

Ludivine

Answer (score 0):

The number of emails sent with **TEST** in subject is negligible, compared to your total volumes. Also, assuming you mainly perform those tests towards the work emails of you and your colleagues, these emails will only be visible for that single domain. Hotmail, Gmail etc. will never see them - hence they will not be impacting your reputation here.